# Can't import jersey in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I try to demo web service using Restful.

I don't know why . I can't import jersey.

I had added jersey library in Netbeans.
[image: This is my error]

[This is link tutorials](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-restful-java-client-with-jersey-client-example/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using Jersey 2 libraries, and you're trying to import Jersey 1 classes. You can see that the javax.ws.rs.client.Client`is imported correctly. This is the`Client` used for Jersey 2. You would use it like

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request().get();
```

**See also:**

- [Jersey 2 Client documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much.